# Regex match for object creation in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am searching the body of the constructor(s) of classes to find out any composition association between classes. So I have decided to use the following regex to perform this matching:

```
String regex = "(" + "^[this.]" + attribute.getName() + "=" + "|" + "^[this.]" + attribute.getName() + " =" + "|" + "^" + attribute.getName() + "=" + "|" + "^" + attribute.getName() + "=" + ")";
```

A class member might be initialized in the constructor in the following formats:

```
this.objectName =...; (with empty space)
this.objectName=...; (without empty space)
objectName =...; (with empty space)
objectName=...; (without empty space)
```

However, my regex still doesn't work as I expected.

Let's assume that I have initialized *Student student;* in the following constructor:

```
public Submission(long studentID, Date dateSubmitted, float grade){
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.student= new Student();
    this.grade = grade;
    this.dateSubmitted = dateSubmitted;
}
```

And my regex should be dynamically created as:

```
String regex = "( ^[this.]student= | ^[this.]student = | ^student= | ^student = )";
```

if we assume that **body** is the content of the **Submission(..)** constructor

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(body);

if(m.find()) {      ((ClassStructure)abstractStructure).addAssociation(AssociationType.COMPOSITION, node.getName());
    isFound = true;
}
```

*isFound* should be initialized as *true* at the end of the compilation. In fact, it is not.

Could you please tell me how should I re-write the regex?

Comment: _"doesn't work as I expected"_ -- what did you expect and what are you getting? Why do you think those expressions have anything to do with composition?  You can't make that determination based on a regex, you need a Java parser and static analysis.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry for not explaining clearly. I am already using JavaParser library. However, this library can't perform this task that's why I need to find out by writing some functions which check the association. I have initialized a member of a class in the constructor as following: "this.student= new Student();" so I am expecting a match between the body of the constructor and the attribute name but unfortunately it doesn't..

Comment: What do you believe the regex `[this.]` does, and why do you believe so? My best guess is that you meant `(?:this\\.)?`, i.e. the *optional* sequence of characters `this.`, and your regex certainly doesn't do that. Perhaps you should re-read whatever regex guide you have, because you are way, waayyyy off. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for meaning of `[]`.

Comment: Your regex should be `"^(?:this\\.)?" + Pattern.quote(attribute.getName()) + "\\s*="`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VLZIjb/1) for demo.

Comment: @Andreas thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are searching for this keyword in the beginning of the line, you don't get the desired results. Try to change your regex with this;

String regexTwo = "( (?:this\.)?" + attribute.getName() + "= | " + "(?:this\.)?" + attribute.getName() + " = )";

Comment: Do you believe `[this.]` is for matching a keyword? *(Hint: It's not)*

Comment: You are right, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by the help of Andreas and Erdi Izgi. The following regex works perfectly:

```
String regexTwo = "( (?:this\\.)?" + attribute.getName() + "= | " + "(?:this\\.)?" + attribute.getName() + " = )";
```